# C++; Is there a way to get my Switch function to reject a valid and invalid answer together?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, visual-studio-2022

So I've been learning how to use the "switch" statement recently. I decided to do some practice exercises. The code I show in my sample code below is one I came up with myself as a solution for a "Cola Machine" beginner exercise I found on a website "cplusplus". The exercise problem text can be found as a multi-line comment at the top of my code. Though, I did decide to try to make my code do more than what was required of the exercise.

For the most part, this code works exactly how I want it to. At first I even struggled to figure out how to get the code to repeat the user input in the line `switch (cin.get())`, if they had entered an invalid answer, but I solved this issue by nesting the "switch" statment inside of a "for" statement, `for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++)`, and having the invalid answers decrement the counter ( `x--;` ). Not sure if that's a practical solution, but it's the one I came up with.

The only time my program doesn't run as intended is when a multiple character input that contains both valid answers and invalid answers is entered into the program (i.e. "-1" or "17"). The latter example outputs the statement for only the valid part of the answer, the statement for case '1', where as the former example outputs the statements for invalid answers and valid answers, so the default case and case '1'. [Example for input "-1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L6xe.png)

I'm wondering if that's just a problem that is inherent to using using "switch" statements in general, or if there's a practical solution I've yet to learn. I'm using a book to learn how to code, "C++ How To Program" by H.M. Deitel/P.J. Deitel, and they had given me a sample code for a letter grade counting program that can be found in my previous question on here. And I found that this same problem occurs in that sample code.

I'd be happy to hear any and all solutions, thank you ! :)

```
/* Write a program that presents the user w/ a choice of your 5 favorite beverages (Coke, Water, Sprite, ... , Whatever).
Then allow the user to choose a beverage by entering a number 1-5.
Output which beverage they chose.

>> Modify the program so that if the user enters a choice other than 1-5 then it will output "Error. choice was not valid, here is your money back." */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{
     string drink1 = "Water", drink2 = "Coke", drink3 = "Pepsi",
        drink4 = "Orange Juice", drink5 = "Powerade";

     string choose_text = "\n\nChoose your preferred drink: ", chosen_text = "\nYou have chosen: ";

     cout << "1.) " << drink1.append(17 - drink1.length(), ' ') << "2.) " << drink2.append(17 - drink2.length(), ' ')
         << "3.) " << drink3.append(17 - drink3.length(), ' ') << "4.) " << drink4.append(17 - drink4.length(), ' ')
         << "5.) " << drink5.append(17 - drink5.length(), ' ') << choose_text;

    for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
        switch (cin.get()) {
            case '1':
                cout << chosen_text << drink1 << endl;
                break;

            case '2':
                cout << chosen_text << drink2 << endl;
                break;

            case '3':
                cout << chosen_text << drink3 << endl;
                break;

            case '4':
                cout << chosen_text << drink4 << endl;
                break;

            case '5':
                cout << chosen_text << drink5 << endl;
                break;

            case '\n': case ' ':
                x--;
                break;

            default:
                cout << "\nError. Choice was not valid.\nPlease enter an option 1 - 5." << choose_text;
                x--;
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::cin.get()` would just take one char. for `"-1"`, it would return `'-'` then with your loop, it takes next char `'1'` (which is correct.)

Comment: This question may need more focus.  On the surface, you seem to be asking about `switch` usage, but I think your _real_ question is about how to read user input that might be multiple characters.

Comment: Read the whole line with `getline`. Test that what you read is exactly one character, and If it is, use the `switch.` If it isn't, inform the user they screwed up and loop back to start again. I find using a function helps a lot. In a function you can loop forever and only return when the user provides a valid input. The calling function now looks simpler because it doesn't have all the input code in it and can focus on doing one thing.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help ! I believe you may have helped me sufficiently. I'm not quiet sure how I would otherwise word this question, but I am going to try out some of the solutions that have been presented :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
int answer;
cin >> answer;
```

That will retrieve an integer value from the user instead of a single character. That solves part of your problem.

Now, let's look at your loop. Ick. Let's try this:

```
bool keepWorking = true;

do {
     keepWorking = false;

     int answer;
     cin >> answer;
     switch (answer) {
         ...
         set keepWorking to true on the bad answers
       
     }
} while (!cin.eof() && keepWorking);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I really appreciate your help ! :)

Comment: So I gave your solution a try and it works great for the most part ! It solved the issue of entering an invalid answer such as "-1". But it presented a totally new problem of entering an answer with any non-integer characters such as "w" or "&". These answers, for a reason that is beyond my understanding, completely break the code and send it on an infinite loop of outputting only the default case. It also doesn't account for any entering of decimals, but that's just me being picky.

Comment: Using `cin >> intvalue` is going to have that kind of problem. The solution is to use `getline` and parse the input yourself. That gives you the choice of issuing errors far more readily. Your teacher probably taught you this `cin >> ` stuff, but you'll never see professional programmers using it.